# Draw star from mario

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This code draws a star from mario. It's somewhat simple, but I feel like it could be a lot shorter. Do you have any suggestions?

```
from turtle import Turtle

a = Turtle()
#size of square side
side = 20
#number of squares in a row
numSquares = 17
a.speed(11)
a.hideturtle()

#defines how to fill color in a square 
def square(color):
    #sets color to color that you set(code down below)
    a.color(color)
    a.begin_fill()
    #makes square
    for counter in range(4):
        a.forward(side)
        a.right(90)
    a.end_fill()
    a.forward(side)


#moves the num of squares back and up one for next row
def nextRow(numSquares):
    a.up()
    a.back(side * numSquares)
    a.left(90)
    a.forward(side)
    a.right(90)
    a.down()

def row(colors, numbers):
    numsquares = 0
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        for i2 in range(numbers[i]):
            square(colors[i])
        numsquares += numbers[i]
    nextRow(numSquares)
a.up()
a.goto(-200,-100)
a.down()

#above code makes below code work (ig) also does nextRow

#sets the color for the first 17 boxes white
colors = ["white"]
numbers = [17]
#nextRows automatically
row(colors, numbers)

#You can also set colors to variables
wh = "white"
bl = "black"
y = "yellow"
#sets the first 1 box white, the next 4 black, and so on
colors = [wh, bl,wh,bl,wh]
numbers = [1, 4, 7, 4, 1]
row (colors, numbers)

colors = ["white", "black", "yellow", "black", "white","black","yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow", "black", "white","black","yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow", "black","yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [2, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 2]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [3, 1, 9, 1, 3]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [3, 1, 9, 1, 3]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [4, 1, 7, 1, 4]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","yellow","black","yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [3, 1, 3, 1, 1,1,3,1,3]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","yellow","black","yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [2, 1, 4, 1, 1,1,4,1,2]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","yellow","black","yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [1, 1, 5, 1, 1,1,5,1,1]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [1, 5, 5, 5, 1]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [6, 1, 3, 1, 6]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [6, 1, 3, 1, 6]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white", "black", "yellow","black","white"]
numbers = [7, 1, 1, 1, 7]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white","black","white"]
numbers = [8, 1, 8]
row (colors, numbers)
colors = ["white"]
numbers = [17]
row(colors, numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, I recommend focusing on more data-oriented approach.
Separate your data from your execution code. It will make:

- Easier for the future if you want to draw something else (just pass different data).
- Your execution code cleaner and shorter.

I like how you tried to optimize your data a bit by drawing multiple squares in a row if they are of the same colour, now just put the row data together so that they make sense.

There are multiple way how to model this, but the closest to what you currently have I would do this:

```
image_data = [
#first row
{
    "colors": ["white", "black", "yellow", "black", "white","black","yellow","black","white"],
    "numbers": [1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1],
},
#... more rows
]
```

Then you can simply iterate over this list and call your `row` method for each item in it.

Other points:

- Saving colours in variables has definitely positives and negatives, but I think I would do it. The main positive I see is making sure you won't have a typo in the colour. I would still name them `white`, `black` and `yellow`, not trying to make shortcuts.
- I would decompose your `row` function and create function, that handles single colour/square-count combination for more clarity and separation.
- `numSquares` should be named `num_squares` by convention, but the name is confusing anyway and needs improving.
- Your `nextRow` (also bad name by convention) can probably be a lot simpler and without need of `numSquares` parameter by using `goto` function.

Comment: Why are the colors and numbers in quotes?

Comment: That's how you work with dictionaries in python. It is not JSON although it looks similar.

Comment: How exactly could I make my function simpler? I can't think of anything

Comment: I wrote you quite detailed points sir. If you want to ask about something more specific, go ahead. But don't ask me to answer again :-)

Comment: Iterating over rows would be better than goto. Why did you go with that?